# Как в видеофайле найти пики громкости?

Tags: python, java, видео, ffmpeg, flv

Есть видеофайлы, разбиты по суткам, там есть метки с камер датчика движения. По движению отмечаются некоторые точки, от которых в интервале 5 секунд видео считается активным. Объединяем все активные периоды, остальное вырезаем из файла.

И всё бы ничего, только там почти всегда что-то движется :) Т.е. итоговый файл длится около 23 часов. Видео файл со звуком, так вот интересующие нас события(а их всего около 200 в сутки) не плохо так шумят. Нужно как то понять по видео ряду в какие моменты времени амплитуда звукогого сигнала превышает заданную... Дальше я уже `ffmpeg`, например, всё сам сделаю.

Желательно что-нить на `python` или `java`.

Но если есть какие-то решения бесплатные, от совета не откажусь.

Изначально формат видео `.flv`, но тут сконвертнуть не проблема.

Comment: для начала не понятно, зачем пытаться определить шум по _видео_ ряду, если это можно сделать по аудиосоставляющей клипа? нe а далее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73227271/finding-peaks-in-audio-signal-using-numpy-and-scipy

Comment: Плюсую `scipy.signal` и `librosa`

Comment: @strawdog, да это понятно, просто обрисовал конкретную ситуацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наличие энергии в звуковом файле можно определить с помощью этих двух функций:

```py
# мощность дискретного сигнала (пропорциональна энергии)
def power(signal):
    return np.dot(signal, signal) / signal.shape[0]


# величина SPL в децибелах
def spl(signal):
    rms = np.sqrt(np.dot(signal, signal) / signal.shape[0])
    spl = 20 * np.log10(rms / 0.00002)
    return spl
```

Сам звуковой сигнал в python можно получить с помощью библиотеки soundfile или librosa.